# cxf exposing subclasses of abstract class

Tags: java, cxf, subclass

My (simplified) situation:

**Service** @WebService
    Container getContainer() @WebMethod

**Container**
    void setObjects( ContainableObjects[] objects )
    ContainableObjects[] getObjects()

**ContainableObjects** [abstract]
    void setName(String name)
    String getName()
    void doSomething()

**ContainedString** [extends ContainableObjects]
    void setValue(String value)
    String getValue()
    void doSomethingElse()

**ContainedInt** [extends ContainableObject]
    void setValue(int value)
    int getValue()
    void doAnotherThing()

These POJO objects already exist. I am using the Eclipse tools to generate CXF code.

At the moment, Service.getContainer will give me a representation of the container. However, CXF will not send any more information than would be contained in a ContainableObject object. Thus, the client does not receive the value information stored in the subclasses.

This simplification does not quite show the reason for using subclasses, but I assure you this reason exists.

Obviously, I need to tell CXF that there are implementing subclasses. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found the solution.

The CXF documentation might be very consise, but the documentation of the standards and frameworks it relies on isn't.

For this problem, the documentation on JAXB helped me a lot.

The actual solution: 
The class ContainableObject needed to be annotated with: 
@XmlSeeAlso({ContainedString, ContainedInt}).